# If jquery's form validation is ok, then I want to run a function before submitting the form

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using this to validate my form and it is fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myform").validate();
    });
```

But I need to run a function before the form submits but only if validation has passed.  When I try to add the function after the validate, like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#myform").validate();
         $('#submitButton').click(function() {
            ...
         });
    });
```

it runs even when the form fails validation.

I've also tried putting the validate function within the submitButton click and the same thing happens -- the function runs even if the form fails validation:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#submitButton').click(function() {
            $("#myform").validate();
            ...
            ...
         });
    });
```

Comment: maybe you should use `.validate()` as a condition, not even as a stand-alone function? e.g.: `if ($("#myform").validate()) { /*whatever*/ }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a callback.

```
$("#myform").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
     // do other stuff for a valid form
     form.submit();
   }
})
```

[Source](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).